# A random sample of the people in a country

Tags: internal-consistency, society

Suppose I'm a rich, well-connected psychological scientist with a lot of spare time, and I'm sick of [WEIRD](http://lesswrong.com/lw/17x/beware_of_weird_psychological_samples/) science.

> `WEIRD` is an acronym of `Western, Educated, Industrialized, Rich & Democratic`, which are characteristics of almost all the participants in almost all studies in psychology. This is due to the fact that normally participants for a study would be whoever's available, that being mostly students in the same institution.

*My* research is too important to chance skewed results. I want statistical accuracy. For that I need a  **real random sample** of the human population. That is, if I need `n` people for the study, each person in the country should have a `n / <size of population>` chance of being in the study. This should include **everyone** (as much as possible).

Luckily, it's a rather simple study to perform. I just need a few second with each participant. They don't even have to know they're in the study.

#### What's to best way to approximate a random sample of the population?

This is a sociological study, so if your solution introduces [intervening variables](http://sociology.about.com/od/I_Index/g/Intervening-Variable.htm) they have to be something very objective.

**What I've considered:**

- Facebook (/Twitter etc): No good, likelihood of having an account is connected to many other variables such as age, economical status etc.
- Central stations / airports: Better, but would miss the very rich and very poor. Some people (businessmen) would have a much higher probability to participate that others.
- The country's databases (or Google's) - as suggested by @notstoreboughtdirt: Would work but I don't have access.

**Notes:**

- I have a lot of resources but would rather use them sparingly.
- I can do without small kids and very old people, if it's easier.
- I want to have as little publicity as possible, so it doesn't influence the results. I would rather meet with people without them hearing anything about me or the study in advance, but it's not mendatory.
- **Bonus:** If I can use the same method for my worldwide study.

**Edit:** I added the tag `reality-check` to encourage out-of-the-box answers. I would accept some craziness for better results, although simplicity is preferred. (There isn't an actual study!)

Comment: That's a problem that statisticians face on on a daily basis. You may have good answers on academia.stackexchange or statistics.stackexchange.

Comment: Off topic. This isn't really statistics, this is more of a social sciences question...depends on what is being surveyed. Academia.SE might be the best fit.

Comment: "My research is too important..." Na, it isn't. ;-)

Comment: @Karl I'm kidding, others, I was looking for something creative, not necessarily practical. I don't actually have a study I want to run

Comment: Studies with WEIRD bias  happen because lazy researchers interview students in the campus since that requires the least amount of effort. If you want different opinions visit working class neighborhood, visit a church, shooting range, golf club etc.   Also WEIRD are part of the population by excluding hem you introduce bias. Read how the http://righteousmind.com/ authors found that they don't have to go to different country to hear a different opinion, they just had to step into a blue collar bar.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have formulated the question it results that you need to interview / interact with the participants. In this case you just cannot have a perfectly representative sample of the entire population, unless you are studying the population of a very small very homogeneous country with particularly lax rules about personal data protection and ethics of sociological / psychological studies.

Since you are trying to sample the entire population you cannot rely on sampling people on the street etc. because simply some people won't be there. You may try to compile a database of all the people in the country and select from it; or, alternatively, you may try to decompose the population into various segments and then go to where those segments live. The second approach is generally more practical, but for this question it has the disadvange that it relies on previous ideas about the structure of the population.

- Difficulty #1: Unregistered or misregistered people. Some countries (but not all) maintain population databases which are supposed to record the identity of every inhabitant. If the country does not do that (the United Kingdom is an example) then you are obviously out of luck. Supposing that the country *does* maintain a population database you run into problems of data quality. Some people have emigrated permanently or temporarily. Some people have immigrated legally or illegally. When the authorities themselves have no precise idea of how many people are in the country, how can you hope to obtain a perfectly representative sample?
- Difficulty #2: Section of the population which won't cooperate. In most countries there are significant segments of the population which do not cooperate with the police, sociologists, psychologists, and generally avoid speaking with people outside their group; for example, thieves, members of infractional groups, monks, nuns, or particularly observant followers of certain religions. Then you have the problem that you are not allowed to speak to members of some segments of the population, for example children below a certain age.
- Difficulty #3: Self-selection. Unless you are a member of the State Secret Police, people can freely chose whether to speak to you or not. Your study can only include people who chose to speak to you. That's self-selection; you are selecting against introverted, secretive, or busy people.

The conclusion is that a perfectly representative sample cannot be obtained. Reputable polling organizations have methodologies to work around the difficulties and generate the best sampling they can, which is the best suited for each specific study; usually such organizations publish their assumptions and sampling methods, so that the representativity of the sample can be assessed independently.

Answer (score 0):

Many if not most countries endeavor to track or at least count their residents. In the US this is done using SSN. They generally put some effort into guarding these databases, but a lot of resources and a disregard of research subjects consent probably means you can work around that. Simply pick a random person out of the list and start stalking. If some class of people (dead) don't work for you over sample and drop them.

Slightly more practically; establish the number of people in the target population n and give each unique person your research team encounters a x/(n-y) chance to be included, x being the study's target number of people and y being the number of unique people encountered. Be sure every person in the counts is unique across all researchers.

Comment: I wasn't aware that these databases are open for citizens to browse... Because they're not

Comment: Not only that, SSN databases don't necessarily keep accurate contact info, or indeed, any at all for some people.  For instance, you might use a mail drop for W2 & IRS forms, or not even file them if you're long-term unemployed.

Comment: I suggest government tracking numbers simply as a way to generate lists of people to pick from, they may help in finding some people but that is not quite what I read the question to be asking. I took "a lot of resources" to mean connections which could be used either to cause a data breach or get official access to those records. If this is meant to further a real world project it is off topic of worldbuilding.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to actually meet with each person in order to do the research, you might be able to do it with drones that have video and audio capability. This would allow you sample a larger area than you could quickly and easily do on foot.

However, if you're really trying to go about getting samples from all over the planet, you are going to have a very time consuming project if you have to do it all yourself. Some possible solutions might be:

- Go there yourself. Unfortunately, very time consuming.
- Establish a research group in each area you want to sample. They could travel around the country meeting people face to face. Also very time consuming.
- Pay volunteers around the world to meet the people for you. Social workers, postal deliverers, medical organizations, [Peace Corps](https://www.peacecorps.gov/), Red Cross, [Doctors Without Borders](http://www.doctorswithoutborders.org/), [humanitarian organizations](http://www.betterworldhandbook.com/action10(orgs).html), [Avaaz](https://www.avaaz.org/page/en/), [Greenpeace](http://www.greenpeace.org/usa/), [Oxfam](https://www.oxfam.org/), police officers, clergy, local social workers, [data mining companies](http://lifehacker.com/the-top-50-companies-that-mine-and-sell-your-data-and-1482645222), activist groups interested in your cause, etc., might be able to help pick people at random for you. Might be ok, but you might not be able to make sure the tests are performed according to your standards. You might be able to get around this problem if you have the interviews recorded by the volunteer.
- If your research is **extremely** important, the military or information/intelligence branches of your government might feel it is in their best interests as well to promote your research. Convince the CIA they need the data and wow, you'll get your data!
- The people could perhaps meet the people in person, or perhaps just drive to a city and use a drone to fly around and meet people at random. This saves on a lot of leg work, possibly speeding up the process. You might be able to enlist [drone club members](https://www.google.com/search?q=drone%20clubs&oq=drone%20clubs&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) from around the world if you offer them something in return.
- Enlist [Google Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waymo) to help you. Their autonomous fleet of cars travels ALL over the globe and if your research is important enough, they might be willing to help you. They might even allow you to have autonomous drones based on their vehicles that fly around testing subjects via pre-programmed testing protocols while the car is driving around mapping everything. The car could go to an area, allow the drone to fly out, then the drone samples people within it's power range, then meet back up with the car when it's time to move on to a different area. This would allow for the car to recharge the drone between uses.

Comment: Once you select the people, getting to them is assumed easy. The question is about selecting the sample (and making sure the selected sample cooperates, which just means a few seconds of face time)

Answer (score 0):

You need face-to-face interaction all over the world... that means you need minions. Have you considered [a pyramid scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_scheme) or [multi-level marketing campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_marketing)?

A pyramid scheme creates a way of encouraging others to participate in some sort of activity in the hopes of gaining unrealistic riches. It grows exponentially, giving it incredible reach across the populace. At the end of the day, it doesn't pan out for people, but in the meantime, you can use it to get all sorts of things done.

You create some product that you claim everyone is going to want. Heck, you can pick some of the classics, like Cutco steak knives (I'll let you run your own Google searches there). You start selling them and recruiting recruits into your organization. Then, when the pyramid has been running for a month or so, you send a message out to all your minions that you need to do a bit of market research so that you can figure out how to improve sales... and you have all of the levels of your pyramid find people and run your psych study. People who are bought into pyramid scheme will tend to show considerable loyalty to you because of the [sunk cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost#Loss_aversion_and_the_sunk_cost_fallacy). You probably don't have to explain how this study will help you improve sales, just convince them that it is important that they do this as honestly as possible.

This gives you reach all over the place and the ability to reach random people all over.

Comment: That has the intervening variable of "being gullible"